# Plastic SCM can't detect repository on cloud

Tags: unity-game-engine, repository, plasticscm

[Client Configuration Wizard on my pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmbUm.png)

I was trying to access the repository of a game being developed in our company. Plastic SCM can't detect any repository from the organization, but can detect from others. Other members of the organization can access the repository just fine, and it can easily be detected once plastic scm is opened. How can I access the repository on my end?

[Client Configuration Wizard on my workmate's pc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HyNTB.png)

Answer (score 0):

Its probable that you don't have view permissions to the Organization, you need to ask the owner of the Organization to validate this in the **Repositories** view and **Repository server permission** from the PlasticSCM interface:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhCtO.png

Check you are not denied in those permissions.